# Where to find validator heartbeat stored on substrate Blockchain

Tags: validator, substrate-archive

I'm looking for a place in Substrate where it stores `validator heartbeat`. I have gone through the staking pallet and I was unable to find it. Where do I need to look for it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should check that in pallet-im-online.

https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/8fb4138d73ad88a19331c30c36ba91796c5846e1/frame/im-online/src/lib.rs#L416.